# c# how to create an executable file so people without a compiler can run it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, exe, sudoku

c# how to create an executable file so people without a compiler can run it
I've created a Sudoku console application and it's amazing..
how can i send it to someone who don't have a visual studio so he can run it in his computer..like video games and this kind of stuff

Comment: Build it in **Release** mode, then got to `project/bin/Release` and grab the `.exe` from there. Make sure you target a `.NET` Framework version that he has.

Answer (score 2):

Just build your application in release and ship the executable you find in:

```
<YourProjectPath>/bin/Release/<YourProject>.exe
```

Comment: @BarIttah well, you haven't said a word about another SO in your post.

Comment: @BarIttah - I am not a Mac user but on the top of my head I would think of using a Windows Virtual Machine or booting directly on a Windows OS. This is out of the scope of the original question, so I would advise asking this on a separate question.

Comment: @BarIttah, you would install mono and run the .exe via that. Last laugh on you sonny-jim...

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can create an installer for your app, for example using the free and powerful [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). There are tons of tutorials and samples on Internet regarding Inno Setup, covering pratically any need.

For example, there are scripts able to check, while installing your app, if the target PC has the .NET version needed for your application to run properly and there are scripts to download and install (even silently) the needed .NET framework.

With an installer, your users will be able to install and run your application simply running your setup executable, downloaded from your website, for example.

I think it's a good idea to spend some hours to learn something so useful.

I spoke about Inno Setup, but there are several others installers ready for your needs: [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is another example of free installer (even if its language is a bit harder to learn). Or WIX, Setup Factory, InstallShield... but some of them are not free.